# How can I convert a string to html code obtained from a function?

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting string from function `{{convertFormat(query[column.field],column.type)}}`, but mine need do transition to next line. I'm do so  `return value.indexOf('\n') > 0 ? value.replace('\n', '
 ') : value`

I've tried doing via `<p ng-bind-html="convertFormat(query[column.field],column.type)"> </p>`  but show error.

I would like to understand how can I transition string to HTML code.
What would happened so `<p>My text <br /> and nexr line<p>`

Comment: I've done it's!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` property.

If You have declare string in component:

`public myString = 'My text <br /> and next line'`

You can use it in html template like this:

`<p [innerHTML]="myString"></p>`

In Your case the string can be returned from function too.

Answer (score 0):

I've use `<p ng-bind-html="convertFormat(query[column.field],column.type)"> </p>` and add `var Services = angular.module('main.services', ['ngSanitize'])` and it all worked